# How to add a matrix to a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

below is some dummy data.

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
df = data.frame(source = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10",
                       "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X110"),
                Destination = c("X3","X5","X17", "X20", "X20","X1", "X2", "X3", "X7", "X10", 
                                "X13","X15","X7", "X1", "X20","X17", "X2", "X3", "X7", "X10"),
                weight = seq(1,1.95,by=0.05))
```

I then have some odds ratios for `Destinations X1:X3` and there respective standard deviations and I want to randomly sample 10 times from each odds ratio and its corresponding standard deviation

```
OR_dat <- c(1.55,1.39,1.77)

sds <- c(0.2925175, 0.4775346, 0.1603566)
n <- 10

normv <- function( n , mean , sd ){
  out <- rnorm( n*length(mean) , mean = mean , sd = sd )
  return( matrix( out , ncol = n , byrow = FALSE ))
}

RR_neighbour_1 <- data.frame(t(normv(n, OR_dat , sds )))
colnames(RR_neighbour_1) <- c("X1",  "X2",  "X3")
```

What I am really looking for is merging the matrix into the data.frame by looking at the value in the column titled `"Destination"`, matching it up with the column name of the matrix titled `RR_neighbour_1` and then creating additional rows to input the distribution. The output should then end up like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is to merge two data.frames by `Destination`. So you first need to get your second data.frame (`RR_neighbour_1`) into long format (so the same format as the first one, where the different destinations are rows not columns). Then you can simply merge the data.frames with the `merge` function. Argument `all=T` will ensure that the rows for the repeated destinations will be added.

```
RR_neighbour_1 <- reshape(RR_neighbour_1,dir="long",varying = list(1:3),
                          timevar = "Destination",
                          times = colnames(RR_neighbour_1),
                          v.names = "RR_neighbour_1")

merge(df, RR_neighbour_1[,-3], all=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: if you're happy to use the `dplyr` package then it includes SQL-style join functions. You probably want the `left_join` function from that package, which lets you map columns using the `by` parameter. That's an easy way to join two table-like structures.